# How to enable Select Folder by default in UWP

Tags: uwp, directory, windows-10

The Select Folder button is disabled and user cannot choose the same folder although it is perfectly valid. I have to go back a level and re-enter the folder if I want to pick that same folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive from official document, for giving the user a sense of consistency, the folder picker remembers the last location that the user navigated to and will generally start at that location.

In addition, FolderPicker does not automatically select a folder when it starts. If no folder is selected, the Select Folder button is disabled. This behavior is by design. Currently uwp doesn’t support to change it. If you do want this feature, please feel free to submit your feature requirement with Windows Feedback Hub app.